# How do I take in userinput but redirect all of it to another file?

Tags: python, filesystems, data-storage

I have a piece of code and I would like to transfer everything the user types to a different file so that I can keep that information forever. How would I do this? My code is below. Please note that my code is completely in python 3.6.1.

```
username = input('What is your name: ')

with open (username, "w") as u:
    u.write(input())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username = input('What is your name: ')

u=open(username+".txt", "w")
while True:

    print("enter your inputs")
    inp=input()
    u.write(inp+"\n")
    #do something with inputs.
    if(inp=="exit"):
        break

u.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code:

```
username = input('What is your name: ')

with open (username, "w") as u:
    u.write(input())
```

Let's change it to :

```
username = input('What is your name: ')
recordinput = input('This is what you want to record from the user: ')
with open (username, "w") as u:
    u.write(recordinput)
''' Now you can record 'recordinput' in the new file '''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple

```py
username = input("Whats your name?")
info = input("What should I record?")

file = open(username,"w")
file.write(info)
file.close()
```

I prefer using this method.
I'm opening it in the write mode and writing the var info that came from line 2.